# CFChart - flash charts not writing to file

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am upgrading an application that is currently working on ColdFusion MX 7 server to ColdFusion 11 server.
There are some charts in the applications which are generated and then written to files and stored in a folder inside the application itself.
The charts are of type flash.

Now in the new server the problem is that the charts are not getting written to the files.
for ex:

```
<cfchart NAME="Chart1" FORMAT="FLASH" SERIESPLACEMENT="percent"  SHOWBORDER="yes"  SHOWLEGEND="no" TIPSTYLE="MOUSEOVER" LABELFORMAT="percent"  CHARTHEIGHT="400" >   
  <cfchartseries TYPE="bar" SERIESCOLOR="red">   
  <cfchartdata item="H" value="10">   
  <cfchartdata item="G" value="25">   
  <cfchartdata item="E" value="30">  
  </cfchartseries>   

<cfchartseries TYPE="bar" SERIESCOLOR="green">   
  <cfchartdata item="Here" value="60">   
  <cfchartdata item="Goes" value="65">   
  <cfchartdata item="Else" value="70">   
  </cfchartseries>
  </cfchart>   

<CFSET FILE_PATH="#APPLICATION.CHARTSFOLDER#\#IMPORT_DATE#\#Chart1" & ".swf">

<CFFILE ACTION="WRITE" charset="ISO-8859-1"
 FILE="#FILE_PATH#" OUTPUT="#Chart1#">
```

With this code I get an error:

> Variable Chart1 is undefined.

This is working as expected on the current server and I need to move this application to the new server as soon as possible but this error is holding that up.

Interestingly, when I change the format to jpg the chart gets created and written to the file. But the file content is now static and I can't hover over the bars to see their values.

Comment: What options did you select during the ColdFusion 11 installation?  The newer versions of ColdFusion have several things (services) disabled during installation for improved security.  My guess is that you have disabled the services required to create your flash charts.

Comment: i will have to check that with the server administrator. We opted for jpg format instead and the end user has no issues with it.